# Extract information via Powershell regex

Tags: regex, azure, powershell, extract, azure-powershell

I am new in Powershell. I have a file that consists of the following lines. From this file, I want to extract **v1.0.2** only via Powershell.

`2022-09-08T10:52:38.0802281Z Downloading git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/basf-terraform/Terraform_modules/azure_private_endpoint?ref=v1.0.2 for resuc_dls1_pep1...`

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do share your tried code in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a module I build that contains a lot of regular expressions, including one that could help here.

The module is called [Irregular](https://github.com/StartAutomating/Irregular).  You can get started by installing the module (`Install-Module Irregular -Scope CurrentUser`).

In it, there are two regular expressions that can help you out:

- ?<Code_BuildVersion>
- ?<Code_SemanticVersion>

To see the definitions for either, after you've installed and imported, run:

```
?<Code_BuildVersion>
?<Code_SemanticVersion>
```

In your string ?<Code_BuildVersion> that would match '38.0802281' (part of the timestamp) and 1.0.2.  ?<Code_SemanticVersion> will match a version with at least 3 parts, and thus will only find the 1.0.2.

To make this work, there are a few options:

1. Use ?<Code_SemanticVersion> to match

```
$LogLine = '2022-09-08T10:52:38.0802281Z Downloading git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/basf-terraform/Terraform_modules/azure_private_endpoint?ref=v1.0.2'
$logLine | ?<Code_SemanticVersion> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

2. Create a new regex based off of ?<Code_BuildVersion>, using 'v' as it's start:

```
$findVersion = [Regex]::New('
v
(?<Code_BuildVersion>
(?<Major>\d+)
\.
(?<Minor>\d+)
(?:\.(?<Build>\d+))?
(?:\.(?<Revision>\d+))?
)
', 'IgnorePatternWhitespace')

$findVersion.Matches('2022-09-08T10:52:38.0802281Z Downloading git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/basf-terraform/Terraform_modules/azure_private_endpoint?ref=v1.0.2')
```

3. Build your own quick regex to do this.

Basically, you can "distill" the regex above into a shorter form, including the v.  Note that after the -split, we need to force the

```
$FindVersion = 'v\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?'
$matched = 
'2022-09-08T10:52:38.0802281Z Downloading = git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/basf-terraform/Terraform_modules/azure_private_endpoint?ref=v1.0.2' -match $findVersion
$matches.0
```

I will also adjust the ?<Code_BuildVersion> regular expression so that it [does not match when it is preceded by punctuation](https://github.com/StartAutomating/Irregular/issues/126).

After this issue is fixed, you should be able to use either regex to extract out what you'd like.