# How to Loop Through List of Filepaths to Find Specific String within Files

Tags: powershell, command-line

*Edited for clarity*

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere. I'm new to Powershell and have tried searching extensively, but for some reason I keep running in circles so any help is appreciated.

I have a txt file containing the filepaths of a series of files. What I need to do is, for a given filepath, search the contents of the file at that path for a string containing a changelog entry and extract from that a substring containing the software version at the time that file was saved.

I was able to search through one file explicitly named (rather than from a path in a txt file) and get the full string using this:

```
Select-String ": Saved - V" .\samplefilepath.acd | out-file .\VersionFinderResults.txt
```

This gets me a string that looks something like this:

Tests\samplefilepath.ACD:7:2018-02-08 16:37:38.987: Saved - V20.01.00/3489.000

Once I have the full strings, I can use this code to output the substrings to another .txt file:

```
 foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\VersionFinderResults.txt"))
{
    $sub = $line.Substring($line.length-17,8)| Out-File -FilePath .\VersionFinderResults2.txt -append
    
}
```

This gets me the desired substring like this:

20.01.00

Convoluted, I know, but I'm learning. :) These two commands get me every instance of the substring I need, appended one per line in VersionFinderResults2.txt just as I need them. Now I need to bundle it all up in what I assume would be a for loop, looking through a txt file of filepaths and running the above lines on the file at each path in that list.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful. TIA

Comment: I am confused on what your actual question is. Are you looking to combine the 2 commands shown? Are you looking to loop through the directories and just output the version info, or you just want the all the versions from *versionfinder....txt* in a new file? Can you show a before and after for the results you're looking for?

Comment: Apologies, original post has been edited to hopefully clarify. Yes, I am trying to combine the two commands shown, but read through a txt file containing a list of filepaths and execute these commands on the file in each path. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is asking close to the same thing as [this other question I answered the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73693416/extract-information-via-powershell-regex/73694021#73694021)

Putting in the brief answer here.

There's a module I write for RegEx called [Irregular](https://github.com/StartAutomating/Irregular).

In that, there's a regex called ?<Code_SemanticVersion>.

You might be able to:

```
Install-Module Irregular -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module Irregular -PassThru
dir $DirectoryWithYourFiles -Recurse | ?<Code_SemanticVersion>
```

See the other question for more details.